# Force specific cursor for an application

Tags: xorg, cursor

I'm currently using termite (a VTE based terminal emulator) on my desktop.
Because of my monitor being rather large I switched to using a high visibility red cursor.

But as soon as I open up a terminal, the displayed cursor switches to a text selection cursor.

On the one hand, this totally makes sense, on the other hand, I never select text using the cursor, so the other cursor just makes it harder for me to read the text.

Reading through the emulators doc, there is no option to change the displayed cursor.
Is there a xorg / gtk way (whichever is responsible for drawing the mouse cursor) for forcing a specific cursor for an application?

Or should I look into using a different emulator which has this option builtin?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in a tool that hides the cursor when it hasn't moved recently. Try unclutter or the newer unclutter-xfixes [git](https://github.com/Airblader/unclutter-xfixes). Note that xterm has option `pointerMode` to hide the pointer (mouse cursor) when you type.